# write new values to variable but keeping the old value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Example:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'TEST STRING'

-- add to string
SET @String = 'TEST STRING 2'
SELECT @String

--return

'TEST STRING''TEST STRING 2'
```

How could i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append to a string like this.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'TEST STRING '

-- add to string
--tsql 2005
SET @String = @String + 'TEST STRING 2'
--tsql 2008+
--SET @String += 'TEST STRING 2'
SELECT @String
```

Comment: Thx, this was helpful, i needet the idea so i can implement it in my procedure.

Comment: Also you should know that if you are using this method for the first string lets say SET String = String + 'TEST STRING ' you should set String to be an empty string (SET @String = '') otherwise it wont work because whatever you add to NULL is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SET @String = @String + 'TEST STRING 2'
```

In this way you add new value to the old using a concatenation

Answer (score 2):

How about this !

```
SET @String +='TEST STRING 2'
```

This and above answers gives you `TEST STRINGTEST STRING 2`

Play around with Quotes & spaces to get `'TEST STRING''TEST STRING 2'`

Comment: I just ignored the commented lines.But my last two lines make the complete string returned. ;)

Comment: Im not sure why, but i get an error because of the += ,still i see that this should also do the same thing as the above answers. Ty

Comment: Yours may be 2005 so go by `SET @String = @String + 'TEST STRING 2'`